# Using config.ini variables in ldscript.ld

Tags: linker, operating-system, embedded, gnu, ld

In my *config.ini* file I have defined these variables:

```
# Where will system be loaded when started (for which address to prepare it)
LOAD_ADDR = 0x100000
RAM_ADDR = 0x300000
ROM_ADDR = 0x200000
STACK_ADDR = 0x600000
```

Which I then use in the *.data* section of the linker script *ldscript.ld*:

```
SECTIONS {
    .code LOAD_ADDR :
    {  /* This is line 9 */
        kernel_code_addr = .;

        /* instructions */
        *?/boot/startup.asm.o ( .text* )

        *( .text* )
    }
    .data RAM_ADDR : AT(ROM_ADDR)
    {
        kernel_data_addr = .;

        /* read only data (constants), initialized global variables */
        * ( .rodata* .data* )
    }
    .bss :
    {
        *( .bss* COMMON* )

        . = ALIGN (4096);
    }

    /* ... */
}
```

But running *make* fails while linking with this error:

```
[linking build/04_Debugging.elf]
ld:build/ldscript.ld:9: non constant or forward reference address expression for section .data
make: *** [Makefile:87: build/04_Debugging.elf] Error 1
```

When I replace *RAM_ADDR* and *ROM_ADDR* in the code with their values, *make* finishes nicely and everything works.

What causes this error? Why can I use *LOAD_ADDR* with no errors?

Answer (score 0):

The linker does not seem to load the variables you defined in *config.ini*.
You can use `INCLUDE` in your linker script to include another file.
From https://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/ld-2.9.1/html_chapter/ld_3.html

```
INCLUDE filename
    Include the linker script filename at this point. The file will be searched for in the current directory, and in any directory specified with the -L option. You can nest calls to INCLUDE up to 10 levels deep.
```

So if you add `INCLUDE config.ini` to the start of your linker script it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to use the C preprocessor to generate your linker script.
You can use -imacros to load a config.h that defines the symbols you want, then use them in the linkerscript.ld.h and generate the linker script before using it to link

```
gcc -imacros config.h -E linkerscript.ld.h -o linkerscript.ld
```